# Set of all true first-order statements about set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Today a TA claimed that "set of all true first-order statements about sets" is actually a set. After searching around on the net, all I can find is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250043/the-set-of-all-true-statements-of-first-order-logic) on this site, which is about completely different things. So, can anyone give me a proof that this is a set?

EDIT: Or if this is definitely not a set, can someone give me a proof?

EDIT: if you don't believe in the existence of a world we live in so that the notion of truth is meaningful, the question can be rephrase as follow: let $M$ be a model of ZFC, and for each statements (in the first-order language for ZFC) that is true about $M$, we can compute the Godel encoding of such statements in $M$ (where the computation is carried out according to $M$). Now is there an element of $M$ such that (according to $M$) it contains exactly those Godel encoding as above?

EDIT: Let me clarify this, since some people are confused about the crux of the problem and confuse this with a basic question. We are looking for a set with some properties about its elements. Specifically, a set $T$ such that $\sigma\in T$ if and only if $\sigma$ is a true statement. Generally, specifying properties of elements are not sufficient to guarantee the existence of a set; for example the "set" $S$ of all natural number $x$ such that $x\notin S$ does not exist. However, in standard set theory, the axiom schema of restricted comprehension does in fact guarantee the existence of a set $S$ of all elements $a\in A$ that satisfy a first-order property $\phi(x)$. So the obvious attempt to solve this problem is to find a first-order formula $TRUE(\tau)$ that pick out all the true statement. But by Tarski's undefinability of truth, no such formula exist. So if this can be proven to be a set, you need to do something clever. In fact, you might need some sort of proof by contradiction otherwise you will run into the undefinability of truth still. But my feeling is that this one is not a set, but I can't prove it either.

Thank you.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA apparently, a teaching assistant

Comment: claimed that "set of all true first-order statements about sets"... what ?

Comment: "a proof that this is a set" ??? If you mean "the set of all true first-order statements" we mean it in an informal sense: the *collection* of all true...

Comment: Sorry, I made a small omission, the claim is that that "set" is a set (as opposed to say, "set of all sets" which is not a set).

Comment: You have to define a formal theory of sets, like e.g. first-order ZFC and then consider its meta-theory. If $\mathsf Z$ is the collection of ZFC axioms, call $\text {Mod}(\mathsf Z)$ the class of all models of $\mathsf Z$. Then define $\{ σ \mid σ \text { is true in every member of } \text {Mod}(\mathsf Z) \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: no the TA just meant to say the set of all statements that is just true in the world, not just those that can be proved.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: by Godel completeness theorem, they are the same.

Comment: Thus, what do you mean with "true in the world" ? What world ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: "for example, the continuum hypothesis is true or false, even though we can't prove either way; if it's true, throw it in" - exact words from the TA when I asked afterward.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here since you know Tarski's undefinability of truth. If $T$ is your set in question you can define the truth predicate $\phi$ from $T$ via $\phi(x)\equiv{}[x\text{ is a Gödel code }\wedge x\in T]$. What am I missing?

Comment: If your TA meant what you think they did, then it sounds like they're wrong.

Comment: @martin.koeberl: that's why I said it might be some sort of proof by contradiction. That claim you made is only applicable if there is an explicit construction of it. In any cases, I don't really believe the claim is true, but I'm ready to be humbled.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: I don't trust this TA since he has made wrong statements in the past (also, because he is an undergrad just a year above me). But this time I can't exactly showed that he is wrong, since I can't prove that the set does not exist either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some models of ZFC contain their own theories as a set, and some do not.

If there is an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, for example, then an easy Löwenheim-Skolem argument shows that there are many ordinals $\lambda$ where $V_\lambda\prec V_\kappa$, an elementary substructure. Thus, the theory of $V_\kappa$ is the same as the theory of $V_\lambda$, which is an element of $V_\kappa$, since $V_\lambda$ is a set structure in $V_\kappa$, which can form its theory. So $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC containing its own theory as an element.

Meanwhile, if there is a transitive model of ZFC, then there is a least such model, the Shephardson-Cohen model, the least $L_\alpha$ that is a model of ZFC. This model is pointwise definable, meaning that every element of it is definable without parameters. But no pointwise-definable model of ZFC can have its own theory as an element, (similar to Tarski's theorem on the non-definability of truth) since if it did this theory would be definable and we would be able to use the fixed-point theorem to find a sentence asserting it's own falsity, which is a contradiction. Alternatively, if a model is pointwise definable, then the theory of the model contains the definitions of all the various ordinals of the model, and the theory tells you how to order them, and so the model would realize that every ordinal is countable, contrary to ZFC. Thus, one can see that no $\omega$-standard Paris model (a model in which every ordinal is definable without parameters) can contain its own theory as an element.

The previous examples are both involving transitive models of ZFC, which is the best kind of case, for we have an agreement between the $\omega$ of the model and in the meta-theory. But let me point out that the concept of "containing your own theory" is problematic for models that are not $\omega$-standard, and one would have to say more about what was meant for this case. The problem is that the theory of a model is defined externally to the model, and consists of entirely standard sentences in the meta-theory. But no $\omega$-nonstandard can have such a set inside it. One might ask for a set in the model whose standard part is the theory, and this is possible, even for models of ZFC that think $\neg$Con(ZFC). The reason is that every model of ZFC has an elementary extension $\bar M$, such that any desired set of natural numbers is coded as the standard part of a set in the model $\bar M$. And so every model of ZFC has an elementary extension to a model $\bar M$ of ZFC, such that the theory of $\bar M$ is coded as an element of $\bar M$.

Comment: Thank youuu! This is exactly what I am asking for! 2 things: (a) is it possible to avoid inaccessible cardinal in your first argument? (b) can you explain "$\omega$-standard" since it was not mentioned in my set theory class?

Comment: Omega-standard means that the models have the standard Omega. This has a consistency strength exceeding Con(ZFC). So one cannot completely eliminate the inaccessible, although it can be weakened.

Comment: This is really insightful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Basically the issue is that the claim is ill-defined. Truth **is always relative** to a structure. You can ask for truth of some sentence in some structure, but never **absolute** truth of any sort. So if the claim was "There is a set of all first-order sentences of set theory that are true in $M$, where $M$ is a model of ZFC." then ZFC itself cannot prove this claim, and hence he is essentially wrong.

There is a way to axiomatize truth without structures, but it is certainly not what the TA you quote is doing, and even then any theory of truth that has sufficient arithmetic cannot have a computable deductive system. I can make my claims in this paragraph precise on request.

---

Now that you've added the second "EDIT" section, your question here is clear and is answered by JDH's answer. I just want to emphasize that the answer is "It **depends on $M$**." (which is precisely why I said the TA's claim is wrong), since if it did not depend on $M$ then the existence of such a set would be either provable or disprovable in ZFC itself. If it is provable, then ZFC proves Con(ZFC), and so ZFC is inconsistent. If it is disprovable, then ZFC proves the non-existence of a model of ZFC that has the full power-set of the naturals, which set theorists who subscribe to ZFC do not believe. Either way, the TA's claim cannot be proven as far as is known today.

Comment: If you don't believe that we live in a actual universe of set where the notion of truth is absolute, then the question still make sense with a simple rephrase: let $M$ be a model of ZFC, for any first-order statement $\sigma$ about $M$, let $"\sigma"$ be the Godel encoding of $\sigma$ in $M$. Question: does there exist in $M$ a subset of natural number such that it contains exactly all and only $"\sigma"$ for all $\sigma$ that is true about $M$. All notions of subset and natural number in the previous sentence of course are all according to $M$.

Comment: @carrotomato: The whole point is that you cannot even define such a notion of "absolute truth" so whichever TA made that claim is making a meaningless claim. Secondly, your attempt to rephrase is not solving the main issue. Indeed **if you have a model $M$ of ZFC**, then there **indeed is** a set of all sentences true in $M$. However, ZFC **cannot prove** the existence of a model of ZFC, unless ZFC is inconsistent. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, there is such a set, IN THE EXTERNAL UNIVERSE! The question is whether it is in the model.

Comment: @carrotomato: Well your elaboration about Tarski's undefinability theorem showed that you do not actually understand ZFC set theory properly, and hence don't see why your claim is ill-defined. There is no such external universe unless you are referring to the **completely separate meta-system** which would have to be **not the same as** the set theory under discussion, otherwise the incompleteness theorem will demolish the claim's meaningfulness. You cannot say "is a set" as if there is some ambient absolute universe that you can access.

Comment: There is your model $M$. For each statement true about $M$, perform the encoding of that statement inside $M$, which give you its Godel encoding inside $M$. Now, is there an element of $M$, such that it contains (according to $M$) all those Godel encoding. Happy? And please tell me what exactly is wrong with my elaboration.

Comment: @carrotomato: Okay now I think I know what you're asking. Your original claim was incorrectly phrased, and your rephrasing in the above comment didn't address how you obtained the model $M$ of ZFC, which is why I kept saying that the claim cannot be proven. If on the other hand your question is about **what assumptions** do you need to be able to prove (in ZFC) that there is such a model $M$, then I agree that JDH has answered it, but please  edit your question to match your actual intention, if not it is simply a **wrong** question.

Comment: My original question is according to what my TA said (quote: "for example, the continuum hypothesis is true or false, even though we can't prove either way; if it's true, throw it in"). And if you believe in the existence of some Platonic world of maths then the notion of absolute truth is meaningful and the question make sense. If you don't believe in it, it is simple to rephrase into a more rigorous question, and I don't think people would have mistakenly misinterpreted into something else.

Comment: @carrotomato: That is why I said in both my answer and comments that the TA's claim is wrong as stated. The claim that a set exists (in ZFC) is understood as the claim that one can prove its existence. ZFC **cannot** do so. Your TA is also being sloppy when saying that CH is independent of ZFC. ZFC proves that **if ZFC is consistent** then CH is independent of ZFC. One could work in ZFC+Con(ZFC), but then as I said so many times the claim is **meaningless** without specifying "true in **what model**", since there are many models. I don't know why you want to defend a meaningless/wrong claim.

Comment: @carrotomato: Thanks for editing your question, and I've added to my answer. And I'm not the downvoter of your question, if you're wondering.

Answer (score 0):

To talk about "all true sentences" you need not merely a model. You also need to specify a theory out of which you are going to pick out true sentences.  Without such a step it is easy specify a counterexample to what you report as your TA's claim.  Thus, consider the collection of statements "$X$ is a set" where $X$ ranges over all sets. This collection is not a set.

Comment: I think it should be understood that we are talking about the same signature as ZFC, so there is only symbol $\in$. No reasonable language for ZFC will let you have 1 constant for each set, that's for sure.

Comment: If you are talking about a specific theory with a well-defined notion of sentence, then your question is not really one about truth, but rather the collection of *all* well-formed sentences.  After all the true ones are precisely half of all the sentences (in classical logic anyway).